# Handling both a KeyEvent and MouseEvent at the same time in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I am making a game where the user needs to drag an ImageView onto a GridPane and while they're dragging it I would like them to be able to press a key to rotate the ImageView. I only want them to be able to rotate the ImageView while it is being dragged therefore I set the KeyEvent handler when the drag event starts and remove it afterwards.

Here is the code that sets the handlers:

```
private void setPlacementHandlers()
{
    setOnMouseMoved(event -> trackMouse(event));
    setOnDragDetected(event -> pickedUp(event));
    setOnDragDone(event -> placed(event));
}
```

Here is the code for OnDragDetected:

```
private void pickedUp(MouseEvent event)
{
    //Get variables from Ship
    ShipPart[] parts = ship.getParts();
    int shipSize = ship.getSize();

    Dragboard db = this.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

    ship.getBoard().setDraggedPart(this);

    ClipboardContent cbContent = new ClipboardContent();
    cbContent.putImage(this.getImage());

    db.setDragView(shipImage);

    db.setDragViewOffsetX((partIndex * 50) + mouseX);
    db.setDragViewOffsetY(mouseY);

    db.setContent(cbContent);

    setFocusTraversable(true);
    requestFocus();

    setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> rotate(keyEvent, db, cbContent));
    getScene().onKeyPressedProperty().bind(this.onKeyPressedProperty());

    for(int i = 0; i < shipSize; i++)
        parts[i].setVisible(false);

    event.consume();
}
```

Here is a temporary version of OnKeyPressed that I'm using for testing purposes:

```
private void rotate(KeyEvent keyEvent, Dragboard db, ClipboardContent cbContent)
{
    System.out.println("Potato");
}
```

I have tried setFocusTraversable(true); and requestFocus();

For the purposes of debugging I removed the code that removes the KeyEvent handler after the drag completes and it turns out that the KeyEvent works fine after the DragEvent but not during.

In summary it appears that the issue isn't that the ImageView isn't getting the KeyEvent it almost seems as if the KeyEvent isn't even being generated due to the DragEvent.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: I have also tried adding the KeyEvent handler to another object which then applies the changes to the object I want to change however, that doesn't work. I also tried various combinations of Threads and Tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drag-and-drop action is a native system action.  Any graphic it displays is a native object and not part of a Java application, though the system gives applications limited ability to configure it, to which Java provides access through classes like Dragboard.

Since the dragged object is not a JavaFX Node, there is no way to listen to (most) key events on it.  In fact, it’s quite possible that no Node in your program has keyboard focus while the drag is taking place.

If both the drag source and the drag target are in the same Scene, you can simulate the drag yourself, by placing the contents of your Scene in a StackPane, then placing a “drag pane” in the same StackPane so it’s on top of the contents, with a clip that ensures it will not block keyboard or mouse events for the contents.  The drag pane holds both a copy of the draggable Node (an ImageView in your case), and a Shape which serves to highlight whichever Node is currently under the drag.

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import javafx.scene.shape.Polyline;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class ImageDragExample
extends Application {
    private static final String DEFAULT_IMAGE =
        "http://solarsystem.nasa.gov/images/galleries/618486main_earth_320.jpg";

    private GridPane grid;

    private ImageView preview;
    private ImageView dragImage;
    private Pane dragPane;
    private Rectangle dragPaneClip;

    private Point2D dragStart;
    private Node dragTarget;
    private Shape dragHighlight;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(24);
        grid.setVgap(24);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(12));
        int id = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            Node p1 = createPlaceholder(String.valueOf(row * 4 + 1));
            Node p2 = createPlaceholder(String.valueOf(row * 4 + 2));
            Node p3 = createPlaceholder(String.valueOf(row * 4 + 3));
            Node p4 = createPlaceholder(String.valueOf(row * 4 + 4));
            grid.addRow(row, p1, p2, p3, p4);
        }

        List<String> args = getParameters().getRaw();
        preview = new ImageView(args.isEmpty() ? DEFAULT_IMAGE :
            Paths.get(args.get(0)).toUri().toString());

        BorderPane imageArea = new BorderPane(preview);
        imageArea.setPadding(new Insets(12));

        Region contents = new BorderPane(new SplitPane(grid, imageArea));

        dragImage = new ImageView();
        dragImage.imageProperty().bind(preview.imageProperty());
        dragImage.setFocusTraversable(true);
        dragImage.setOpacity(0);
        dragImage.setOnMousePressed(e -> startDrag(e));
        dragImage.setOnMouseDragged(e -> updateDrag(e));
        dragImage.setOnMouseReleased(e -> endDrag(e));
        dragImage.setOnKeyPressed(e -> rotate(e));

        dragPane = new AnchorPane(dragImage);
        dragPaneClip = new Rectangle();
        dragPane.setClip(dragPaneClip);
        StackPane pane = new StackPane(contents, dragPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        preview.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(this::placeDragImage);
        imageArea.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(this::placeDragImage);
        stage.widthProperty().addListener(this::placeDragImage);
        stage.heightProperty().addListener(this::placeDragImage);
        placeDragImage(null);

        stage.setTitle("Image Drag Example");
        stage.show();
    }

    private void rotate(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println(e.getCode() + " pressed");
    }

    private void startDrag(MouseEvent event){
        dragStart = new Point2D(event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
        dragImage.setOpacity(0.5);
        dragImage.requestFocus();
        dragPane.setClip(null);
    }

    private void updateDrag(MouseEvent event){
        double x = event.getScreenX();
        double y = event.getScreenY();
        double xDelta = x - dragStart.getX();
        double yDelta = y - dragStart.getY();
        dragImage.setTranslateX(xDelta);
        dragImage.setTranslateY(yDelta);

        Node newDragTarget = null;
        for (Node node : grid.getChildren()) {
            if (node.contains(node.screenToLocal(x, y))) {
                newDragTarget = node;
                break;
            }
        }

        removeDragHighlight();
        dragTarget = newDragTarget;
        addDragHighlight(dragTarget);
    }

    private void endDrag(MouseEvent event){
        if (dragTarget != null) {
            removeDragHighlight();
            System.out.println("Dropped on " + dragTarget.getId());
        }

        dragImage.setOpacity(0);
        dragImage.setTranslateX(0);
        dragImage.setTranslateY(0);
        dragPane.setClip(dragPaneClip);
        dragStart = null;
        dragTarget = null;
    }

    private void placeDragImage(Observable o) {
        if (preview.getScene() != null && dragImage.getScene() != null) {
            Point2D point = preview.localToScene(0, 0);
            if (point != null) {
                point = dragImage.getParent().sceneToLocal(point);
                AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(dragImage, point.getX());
                AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(dragImage, point.getY());
                dragPaneClip.setX(point.getX());
                dragPaneClip.setY(point.getY());
                dragPaneClip.setWidth(dragImage.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
                dragPaneClip.setHeight(dragImage.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    private void addDragHighlight(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            Bounds bounds = node.getBoundsInLocal();

            dragHighlight = null;
            if (node instanceof Region) {
                dragHighlight = ((Region) node).getShape();
            }
            if (dragHighlight == null) {
                dragHighlight = new Rectangle(
                    bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY(),
                    bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
            } else {
                // Clone the node's shape by subtracting an empty shape from it.
                dragHighlight = Shape.subtract(dragHighlight, new Polyline());
            }
            dragHighlight.setStrokeWidth(2);
            dragHighlight.setStroke(Color.RED);
            dragHighlight.setFill(null);

            bounds = dragHighlight.getBoundsInLocal();
            Point2D shapeOrigin = 
                node.localToScene(bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY());
            shapeOrigin = dragPane.sceneToLocal(shapeOrigin);

            dragPane.getChildren().add(dragHighlight);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(dragHighlight, shapeOrigin.getX());
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(dragHighlight, shapeOrigin.getY());
        }
    }

    private void removeDragHighlight() {
        if (dragHighlight != null) {
            dragPane.getChildren().remove(dragHighlight);
            dragHighlight = null;
        }
    }

    private Node createPlaceholder(String id) {
        Label label = new Label(id);
        label.setId(id);
        label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #c0c0ff;");
        label.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I'm trying to handle the KeyEvent from the ImageView which IS a JavaFX node, not from whatever is on the dragboard.

Comment: When you perform a drag-and-drop operation, the object being dragged is not your ImageView.  It is a native system object which displays the image passed to DragBoard.setDragView.  During that drag, no Node has keyboard focus, so key presses won’t be seen.

Comment: I know the object being dragged isn't my ImageView but I had no idea that it prevents any Node having keyboard focus. Thanks.